# OpenCV MP4 Creation

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to trying to write MP4 video files using OpenCV, in python.

AVI creation works fine, both on linux and windows, when I use both:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('x.avi', 0, 30, (640, 480))
```

and

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('x.avi', fourcc, 30, (640, 480))
```

and even

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('x', fourcc, 30, (640, 480))
```

.

When I try to save an MP4 however nothing ever saves - using:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"H264")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('x.mp4', fourcc, 30, (640, 480))
```

and

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"AVC1")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('x.mp4', fourcc, 30, (640, 480))
```

No errors occur, just nothing saves.

I've tried everything over the past few days, doing everything to avoid creating the AVI and then converting it to MP4 using ffmpeg as I find that to be horrible practice.

Comment: I guess opencv uses ffmpeg in the videowriter to encode (transcode) and package a video. Maybe you don't have it on your system? As a workaround you can use ffmpeg to convert your avi to mp4.

Comment: Do you think it would work if i installed FFMPEG?

Comment: Isit a python module or an actuall windows program or something

Comment: the documentation on `cv::VideoWriter::VideoWriter` says: *The constructors/functions initialize video writers. On Linux FFMPEG is used to write videos; on Windows FFMPEG or VFW is used; on MacOSX QTKit is used.* I don't think that openCV implements a H.264 encoder and ISOBMFF on its own.

Comment: I have the same problem. Sometimes I get a video and sometimes I get an empty file. Did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -3):

Give right values of the high and width of the frames:

```
import cv2

print ('Press [ESC] to quit demo')
# Read from the input video file
# input_file = 'Your path to input video file'
# camera = cv2.VideoCapture(input_file)

# Or read from your computer camera
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Output video file may be with another extension, but I didn't try
# output_file = 'Your path to output video file' + '.avi'
output_file = "out.avi"

# 4-byte code of the video codec may be another, but I did not try
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')

is_begin = True
while camera.isOpened():
    _, frame = camera.read()
    if frame is None:
        break

    # Your code
    processed = frame

    if is_begin:
        # Right values of high and width
        h, w, _ = processed.shape
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_file, fourcc, 30, (w, h), True)
        print(out.isOpened()) # To check that you opened VideoWriter
        is_begin = False

    out.write(processed)
    cv2.imshow('', processed)
    choice = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if choice == 27:
        break

camera.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code works for me.

Comment: this is the basic example for .avi video, not mp4 as the question requested

Comment: Providing correct width and height values solved a similar problem for me. I had 1920x1080 frames, and incorrectly specified 640x480 (hoping that the frames will be simply truncated when saving). Instead, the mp4 file only contained a small header (~200 bytes). Once I correctly specified dimensions, the video was saved properly.